# Getting the selector from a method directly? NSSelectorFromMethod([[SomeClass someObject] Method])?

Tags: objective-c-runtime

Is it possible?

Comment: Without more context, it is difficult to provide a concrete answer.

Answer (score 4):

The Objective-C runtime has a function called "[method_getName](http://developer.apple.com/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/ObjCRuntimeRef/Reference/reference.html#//apple_ref/c/func/method_getName)" with takes a Method object and returns a SEL.

Answer (score 2):

Alternatively, use:

```
NSSelectorFromString(@"myMethodName");
```

Answer (score 0):

Your example in the header is not quite clear.

But here we go. All selectors for all classes lives int he same namespace. Meaning `doFoo` on the class `Bar`, or `doFoo` on the class `Baz` will both be the same unique selector. This means you do not need to bother with the class in order to get a selector. Two nice ways to do it.

```
NSSelectorFromString(@"doFoo");  // If you have the selector name as a string.
@selector(foFoo);  // If it is selector constant inlined in your code.
```

Your question could also refer to how to return selectors from a method. Since selectors are first class citizens in obj-c, we can pass them around as any variables, and return them from methods. The type of a selector is `SEL`.

```
-(SEL)selectorFromFoo:(Foo*)aFoo;  // Declare a method returning a selector.

SEL sel = [myBar selectorFromFoo:myFoo];    // Get a selector.
[myBar proformSelector:sel withObject:nil]; // Perform this selector
```